# openlayers - clicking on zoom in (+) of clustering strategy

Tags: openlayers

My question is in clustering strategy. For example, if a map contains 3 clusters at the first zoom level and when click on zoom in (+) of a map the clusters gets expanded and divided into smaller clusters and may also contain individual features. I don't know what is the internal process that happening when clicking on zoom in for clustering strategy.

If anyone knows help me in the background process that happening in clustering or give me any suggested link for this.

Comment: OpenLayers is an open-source project so there is nothing stopping you from finding out yourself: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster.js

Answer (score 1):

The answer is easy to find at https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Strategy/Cluster.js Like Kryger said.  Around line 152, you will see a function called cluster.  This is called with the event object like {zoomChanged: zoomChanged}.

Now, if you are interested in editing the way it clusters, you may be interested in changes like the ones proposed for
[reclustering](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3384).

Comment: This reclustering method will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with StyleMap and context:

```
var pointStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        strokeWidth: "${strokeFunction}",
        },{
            context: {
                strokeFunction: function(feature) {
                    if(feature.attributes.count>1) {
                        var count = feature.attributes.count;
                        var stk = Math.max(0.2 * count, 3);
                        return stk;
                    } else return 2;
                }

            }
        });
```

Here I'm showing you a little example of my StyleMap with an internal function to work with the individual or clustered feature's stroke.
You can add functions to work with the values, the border, color, etc.